# How to add specific edit button on table for certain condition?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display the Edit button in my data only if the status stated in my database is 'Full';

In my code below I added an edit button to each status dynamically. What I want to achieve is to only add the `Edit` button to the status that has a value of `Full` only. Let's say I have two data in my database, one Status says `Full` and the other one says `Available`. How do I add the Edit button to the status who has the `Full` data only. Is this possible? Please help.

I've tried this one using echo, but it seems it is an incorrect syntax.

```
<?php 
echo "" ."<?php if($row['status'] == Full) { <a class='editname' href='editnames.php?did=".$row['nameid']."'>Edit</a> } ?>". "";
?>
```

Is this doable in php code?

```
<?php
include "includes/connection.php";
session_start(); // start a session

// query from db
$sql = $connection->prepare('SELECT nameid, name2, name3, name4, status FROM names');
$sql->execute(); // execute query
$result = $sql->get_result(); // fetch result

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<tr><th>Name 1</span></th><th>Name 2</th><th>Name 3</th><th>Name 4</th><th>Status</th><th></th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" .$row["nameid"]. "</td><td>" .$row["name2"]. "</td><td>" .$row["name3"]. ", " .$row["name4"]. "</td><td>" .$row["status"]. "</p></td><td>" ."<a class='editname' href='editnames.php?did=".$row['nameid']."'>Edit</a>". "</td></tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make the conditional status within the `while` loop like this :

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $status = $row["status"] == 'Full' ? "<a class='editname' href='editnames.php?did=".$row['nameid']."'>Edit</a>" : "";
    echo "<tr><td>" .$row["nameid"]. "</td><td>" .$row["name2"]. "</td><td>" .$row["name3"]. ", " .$row["name4"]. "</td><td>" .$row["status"]. "</p></td><td>" . $status . "</td></tr>";
}
```